# Failure when inserting data to DB through php

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions

So I have this exercise where i need to insert (and do various other actions, i did those successfully) data into a very basic database through php insertion, but I don't seem to be able to do so, and I have absolutely no idea why.

Here is my code (disclaimer, i'm only at the beginning of learning php, so any advice would be really appreciated!):

```
<?php 

include 'Connect.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO game ( product_id, product_name, multiplayer, pegi, genre, release_date, dis_id, dev_name) 
VALUES ('"
     .$_POST['product_id']."','"
     .$_POST['product_name']."','"
     .$_POST['multiplayer']."','"
     .$_POST['pegi']."','"
     .$_POST['genre']."',"
     .$_POST['release_date'].",'"
     .$_POST['publisher'].",'"
     .$_POST['developer']."')";

//execute query 
$queryexe = mysql_query($query);
if ($queryexe) { 
mysql_query("COMMIT");
print("<p><font size=\"+1\">Success!</font></p>");
} else { 
print("<p><font size=\"+1\">Error</font></p>");
} 

//disconnect from database 
mysql_close($connectionstring); 

?>
```

It connects to the db, as I'm able to see what's in the *game* table, but i don't know why i'm getting a constant error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm only getting the error message from print, but my flatmate who is busy with a similar db and is connected to it locally (i'm using my university's remote server) is getting an "undefined variable" error message".

Comment: `release_date`, unless it's a number, needs to be in quotes. Quote dates.

Comment: "i'm only at the beggings of learning php, so any advice would be really appreciated" - mysql_? $_POST in a query? font tags??! Lose whatever tutorial you're using and start over. http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: @persongr: you should use mysqli or pdo. product id should not be in quotation

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified since that transaction was incomplete

```
 include 'Connect.php';

  mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

   $query = "INSERT INTO game ( product_id, product_name, multiplayer, pegi, genre, release_date, dis_id, dev_name) 
   VALUES ('"
 .$_POST['product_id']."','"
 .$_POST['product_name']."','"
 .$_POST['multiplayer']."','"
 .$_POST['pegi']."','"
 .$_POST['genre']."','"
 .$_POST['release_date']."','"
 .$_POST['publisher']."','"
 .$_POST['developer']."')";

  //execute query 
  $queryexe = mysql_query($query);
  if ($queryexe) { 
   mysql_query("COMMIT");
      print("<p><font size=\"+1\">Success!</font></p>");
  } else {
   mysql_query("ROLLBACK"); 
      print("<p><font size=\"+1\">Error</font></p>");
  } 

    //disconnect from database 
      mysql_close($connectionstring);
```

You were doing a **commit**, without beggining a **transaction**, and no **rollback** in case of mysql error or failure,

As a recommendation, start working with mysqli and don't use your values concatenated in the  insert statement.

***Edit***

You are missing a quote after the double quote in publisher field

```
 .$_POST['release_date'].",'"
 .$_POST['publisher']."' // <--- this one
```

Comment: Yeah, I know commit is about transactions, i kinda forgot it there. the complete transaction code didn't fix the error though.

Comment: @persongr What's the error it is reporting you? add this `$queryexe = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and print here the error the browser returns.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','DICE')' at line 2"

I entered DICE at the developer field.

Comment: @persongr check my edit on the answer, hope it helps

Comment: I fixed it, and another small one i found, but now the connection times out!

Comment: What do you mean by "times out"? does the data goes into the db? success message gets printed out? Try commenting the connection close at the end of the script to see what happens.

Comment: no it doesn't, and it doesn't seem to be in correct sync. i put some extra data through the terminal, and it didn't show up in the "show data" action i programmed earlier. anyhow, for the time being, i let my flatmate use the remote server with his .php files, and we'll see how this goes.

Comment: You can open another question for that problem, please feel free to accept my answer if it solved your issue, and let me know if i can help you further, Thanks